# Should all monitors be at the same resolution in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I have heard that monitors of different resolutions will have problems in a multi-monitor setup, such as black lines appearing on the screen.

Is this true?

Comment: Resolutions or Refresh Rates, never head of "resolution rates" before?

Comment: It's related to the terminology conflation coefficient.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not true; as with any time you use an LCD display, run each at its native resolution for best results. (For example, on my machine at home I have three displays, one each at 1920x1080, 1680x1050, and 1280x1024, and they all work together just fine.)

One note: While most modern LCD displays have a dot pitch of 72dpi (i.e. 72 pixels per inch), it's possible you may have displays whose dot pitches differ. In that case, running them at native resolution will produce visually odd results; graphical elements of the same pixel size will change actual size depending on which monitor displays them; the higher the dot pitch, the smaller they'll appear. It won't prevent the multi-monitor setup from working, but the resulting behavior will be odd and perhaps jarring; for that reason, I'd recommend having all displays in a multi-head arrangement be of identical dot pitch.

Comment: Why do the dot pitches need to be similar?  Technically, things will work fine.  If the dot pitches are radically different, it'll feel like one monitor is just zoomed in or out from the other.

Comment: @ernie Good point. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I've run multi-monitor setups across Linux, MacOSX and Windows for many years. This includes my "main" machine, with 4 displays. The different resolution of each monitor has never been a problem for me. Though if you decide to mirror a virtual monitor across multiple physical monitors, it's very helpful when the physical monitors all have the same native resolution.

Comment: @Doc Fair enough; I've found it a bit weird when using my Retina iPad as a secondary display for a box whose primary heads are all 72dpi, so felt it worth mentioning. On the other hand, I'd probably get used to the difference if I used my iPad in that fashion more than occasionally. De gustibus, &c.

Comment: @AaronMiller - Well, using your ipad as a display is kind of another ball of wax.. I (mistakeningly?) thought you were referring to connecting multiple monitors to video cards on a single computer.. Still, your resolution differences shouldn't fundamentally stop you.

Comment: @Doc A bit of both; in the answer I (implicitly) describe multiple heads actually plugged into the machine, but the dot-pitch discussion is primarily informed by my experience of using the iPad as a fourth head, connected via radio rather than copper. ("Secondary display" in my prior comment may have been misleading.)

Comment: Big +1. A significant difference in DPI can be a real pain as it can mean e.g. text which is fine on one screen is too small to read on the other. Other than that identical resolutions are nice, but not important.